# Oracle SELECT statement with GROUP BY and multiple WHERE clauses

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having trouble with a select query. See sample data below. I want to select the Sku records where there is no stock quantity for warehouse id 1, but there is stock quantity for warehouse id 2 & 3. Not sure what I'm doing wrong?

**SAMPLE TABLE DATA**

```
Sku         WhseId      Qty
============================
ABC-123     1           6
ABC-123     2           3
ABC-123     3           2
XYZ-789     1           0
XYZ-789     2           1
XYZ-789     3           3
DEF-456     1           0
DEF-456     2           0
DEF-456     3           3
```

**QUERY**

```
SELECT Sku, WhseId, Qty
FROM PRODUCTS
WHERE (WhseId = 1 AND Qty < 1)
AND (WhseId = 2 AND Qty > 0
AND (WhseId = 3 AND Qty > 0)
GROUP BY Sku, WhseId, Qty
```

**DESIRED RESULT**

```
Sku         WhseId      Qty
============================
XYZ-789     1           0
XYZ-789     2           1
XYZ-789     3           3
```

Comment: `WhseId = 1 AND WhseID = 2 AND WhseId = 3` will never ever return you any record.  Check your logic.  There can only be one `WhseId`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you actually want to use EXISTS for this:

```
SELECT Sku, WhseId, Qty
FROM PRODUCTS p
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT 1
 FROM PRODUCTS p2
 WHERE p.sku = p2.sku
 AND p2.whseid = 1
 AND p2.qty = 0)
AND EXISTS
(SELECT 1
 FROM PRODUCTS p3
 WHERE p.sku = p3.sku
 AND p3.whseid = 2
 AND p3.qty > 0)
AND EXISTS
(SELECT 1
 FROM PRODUCTS p4
 WHERE p.sku = p4.sku
 AND p4.whseid = 3
 AND p4.qty > 0)
```

Comment: This is the best answer

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
SELECT Sku
FROM PRODUCTS
GROUP BY Sku
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN WhseId = 1 AND Qty < 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN WhseId = 2 AND Qty > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN WhseId = 3 AND Qty > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   Sku,
   WhseId,
   Qty
FROM
(
   SELECT
      PRODUCTS.*,
      SUM(CASE WHEN WhseId = 1 THEN Qty END) OVER (PARTITION BY Sku)   AS whse1_qty,
      SUM(CASE WHEN WhseId = 2 THEN Qty END) OVER (PARTITION BY Sku)   AS whse2_qty,
      SUM(CASE WHEN WhseId = 3 THEN Qty END) OVER (PARTITION BY Sku)   AS whse3_qty
   FROM
      PRODUCTS
)
  pivotted
WHERE
      whse1_qty < 1
  AND whse2_qty > 0
  AND whse3_qty > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW get_skus_2 AS
SELECT Sku
FROM PRODUCTS
WHERE Qty>0 AND WhseId=2;

CREATE VIEW get_skus_3 AS
SELECT Sku
FROM PRODUCTS
WHERE Qty>0 AND WhseId=3;

SELECT Sku s, WhseId, Qty
FROM get_skus_2 g2 JOIN get_skus_3 g3 ON g2.Sku = g3.Sku
WHERE s IN (
    SELECT Sku
    FROM PRODUCTS
    WHERE Qty=0 AND WhseId=1);
```

Comment: That returns SKUs where warehouses 2 ***or*** 3 have stock, but the OP wants SKUs where warehouses 2 ***and*** 3 have stock.  *(And your `WhseID's` of `0` should be `1`.)*

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution:

```
select sku, whseid, qty
from etst
where sku = 'XYZ-789' and ((whseid = 1 and qty < 1)
or (whseid = 2 and qty > 0)
or (whseid = 3 and qty > 0))
group by sku, whseid, qty;
```

Comment: That's not what the OP wants.  That requires knowing that the `sku` required is `XYZ-789`.  The OP wants a query to find that `sku` based on search criteria...

Answer (score 0):

How about combining IN with a GROUP BY on Sku?

```
SELECT Sku, WhseId, Qty
FROM PRODUCTS
WHERE Sku IN ( 
   SELECT Sku
   FROM PRODUCTS
   WHERE WhseId IN (1, 2, 3)
   GROUP BY Sku
   HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN WhseId = 1 THEN Qty END) = 0
      AND MAX(CASE WHEN WhseId = 2 THEN Qty END) > 0
      AND MAX(CASE WHEN WhseId = 3 THEN Qty END) > 0
)
ORDER BY Sku, WhseId;
```

**Result:**

```
Sku     WhseId Qty
------- ------ ---
XYZ-789      1   0
XYZ-789      2   1
XYZ-789      3   3
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/14d9f/1/0)